# Getting the half of a glyph

Tags: vimrc, gvim, unicode

while trying to add a unicode font, I am getting the half of the font, like in line 239 and 240 in the screenshot:[image]

I have, in my vimrc:

```
set history=700                      "  How many line Vim should remember
set nocompatible                     "  because vim is not vi
"set autowrite                       "  write on shell commands
"set autoread                        "  read on change outside vim
set clipboard+=unnamed               "  Yanks go on clipboard instead.
set ignorecase                       "  Searching ignore case, be smart, highlight match
set smartcase
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set foldmethod=marker
set magic                            "  For regular expressions turn magic on
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l
set spell spl=en_us                  "  Set Spell
set spell
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
set updatetime=300
set tags=tags;/
syntax enable
" let mapleader=","
"}}}

"Formatting {{{
set formatoptions+=o                 "  Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or 'O' in Normal mode.
set formatoptions-=r                 "  Do not automatically insert a comment leader after an enter
set tabstop=2                        "  Tabs width
set shiftwidth=2                     "  Default shift width for indents
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab                        "  but tabs are actually space
set hidden
set autoindent                       "  Indent smartly
set smartindent
set backspace=eol,start,indent       "  Configure backspace so it acts as it should act
set encoding=utf8
colorscheme vimgnome
if has('gui_running')
  if has('gui_gtk3')
    set textwidth=99
    set colorcolumn=100
    set lines=55 columns=155
    set guioptions-=a
    set guioptions-=T
    set guioptions-=e
    set t_Co=256
    set guitablabel=%M\ %t
    " set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ 10
    set guifont=SauceCodePro\ Nerd\ Font
    " set guifont=inconsolata\ Nerd\ Font 12
  endif
endif
```

What is going wrong here?

This is how it actually appears in signcolumn:[image]

Comment: Looks like they are italic. I guess that italic styling is being applied to a non-italic font which pushes those chars outside of the allowed width...? Do they render correctly when non-italic?

Comment: Not really, I have the same problem with default ale error sign (the exclamation under triangle)

Comment: @BLayer: I understand your point, but that is not the case. I have uploaded another screenshot with how it is actually rendered in ale_error sign in signcolumn. kindly have a look.

Comment: It is just wider than a char placeholder

Comment: @MaximKim: Thanks. Is there any solution? Or just that the sourcecodepro+nerd is not going well, have to look for another basefont patched with nerd?

Comment: terminal may not be the culprit, as i am in gvim. Or should I check? I have xterm-256color, though

Comment: @BaRud I don't think so. Other than using chars with "proper" width. Or patching gvim maybe

Comment: Solved. Using the source code `Mono` patched font.

Comment: @BaRud Please post a self answer indicating what solved your problem (and any context that might be useful to others who encounter the same issue.) Thanks!!!

Comment: See also: `:help 'guifontwide'` and `:help gui-fontwide`, you might want to keep your original font and specify an alternate for wide characters only...